# Social Authentication : What should the end application check after user has authenticated on social network?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

I am in the final stages of building my own solution for social authentication and need some help understand the next step. Here's what my application achieves so far: -

1. User clicks on Login with (Google / Facebook / LinkedIn ) and is directed to the appropriate network.
2. User logs-in and allows access to the app. The user is then redirected back to the app.

Now, by the time user returns back to my app, I've following useful data -

A. Unique ID provided by the social network.
B. User's email ID.
C. Other profile information as requested.

**My Question**:

What information should I use on my app to login a user securely? I can check with email and let the user log-in if the email sent by social service matches existing records in my database. This would also make the user login process social network independent, that, if the email sent by social network exists in database; use can login.

If, on the other hand, I use 'unique ID' provided by social network to authenticate user, then the system will not be able to identify a user with same email id; but loggin-in from a different social network; than what they used at the time of first sign-in.

Or should I use both unique ID and email, to authenticate a user? Please advice.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: First of all you should be aware that you will not get an e-mail address for all users. For example users that signed up for Facebook using their mobile often do not have an e-mail set.

Comment: Interesting! Does that also happen with Google and LinkedIn? I'm only supporting three services: Facebook, Google and LinkedIn.